# Calculator crashes after multiplying in C

Tags: c, while-loop, switch-statement, calculator

Hello and thanks for taking the time to read this!

I'm trying to create a basic calculator but I'm running into some trouble..
The calculator is supposed to be continuous and only use the (+ , - , * , / ) operations.

```
  Ex: Calc is on
  result = 0
  +2  (user input)
  result = 2
  *5 (user input)
  result = 10
  % 3 (user input)
  unknown operator. Try again.
  R (user input)
  Final result = 
  Do you want to continue (Y/N)
```

Now i got as far as being able to continuously add or subtract (even then i think its wrong because even if i don't enter a - or + the last result will add the newest entered number).
The big problem arrives when i try to mult or divide. the program crashes and just keeps adding.

I'm guessing this is because i entered a + in the first scanf and then the while loop only works for that +.?? I tried many different variations but can't seem to be able to figure it out!!

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    double result = 0;
    double new_number;
    char symbol;

printf("\t\t*\t+ for [addition]\t*\n");
printf("\t\t*\t- for [subtraction]\t*\n");
printf("\t\t*\t/ for [division]\t*\n");
printf("\t\t*\t* for [multiplication]\t*\n");
printf("\t\tPress 'R' to RESET/EXIT the program");
printf("\n\n\tCalculator is ON\n");
printf("\t-------------\n\n") ;
printf("current value = %.2f\n",result);

scanf("%c", &symbol);   
while (symbol != 'R')
{
    scanf("%lf", &new_number);

    if( symbol=='+')
    {
    result+=new_number;
    printf("The new result is %.2f ", result);
    }
    else if(symbol=='-')
    {
    result-=new_number; 
    printf("The new result is %.2f ", result);
    }
    else if(symbol=='*')
    {
    result*=new_number;
    printf("The new result is %.2f ", result);
    }
    else if(symbol=='/')
    {
    result/=new_number;
    printf("The new result is %.2f ", result);
    }
    else if(symbol== 'R' || symbol== 'r')
    {
    printf("Final Result = %f\n ", result);
    printf("Do you want to continue? (y/n)");
    }
    else {
    printf("Not an operation of the function.\nTry again.");
    }
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you already inspect your program's execution using a debugger? If not, please don't expect us to do so for you ...

Comment: You need to read in a new symbol as well as a new number every time through the loop - otherwise you're just going to go into the same if statement every time. Try changing `scanf("%lf", &new_number);` to `scanf("%c%lf", &symbol, &new_number);`.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm completely new to C. I probably should of mentioned that. is debugging the same as using a compiler? If so then yes, of course i have. I wouldn't just come here and have you guys do all the work... Everything compiles fine. (if that's what your asking)

Comment: I think the origin of your problem is using multiple scanf's to parse a single line. I think when it's looping back to the first scantf("%c",...) it's reading the new line character.

Comment: `scanf("%c", &symbol);   
    while (symbol != 'R')` --> `while(1==scanf(" %c", &symbol) && symbol != 'R')`

Comment: Commander Cor - thanks for the help!! but i have tried that already and it only does the calculation once.
Nighthawk- exactly what i was thinking. but couldn't figure a way around it..

BluePIXY - your code just worked!! thank you soo much! (Now if someone may please explain why it worked would be amazing too!) does it mean entering an operator will be true? and how come we have to use && instead of ||  ???

Comment: and BTW i don't understand why my question got downvoted? what did i ask wrong?? i thought i was pretty specific with the question.
And i used this place as my last resort...but thank you so much to everyone that helped!!!!!

Comment: A debugger is not the same thing as a compiler. A compiler translates one language into another, eg, C into machine code. A debugger enables you to examine your program as it is running to determine where it went wrong. **Learn how to use a debugger immediately**.  Also, this might help:  http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

> BluePIXY - your code just worked!! thank you soo much! (Now if someone
>   may please explain why it worked would be amazing too!) does it mean
>   entering an operator will be true? and how come we have to use &&
>   instead of || ???

It works with BluePIXY's change because now the `scanf(" %c", &symbol)` is part of the `while` loop's controlling expression and as such executed before each execution of the loop body, whereas in your original version it was executed only once before entering the loop.

You should have read in the `*scanf` manual that:

> These functions return the number of input items successfully matched
>   and assigned

- so, the return value is not compared with `true`, but with the number `1`. And of course we have to use `&&` because we want to loop while a character is entered **and** this character is not `'R'`.